Abp.io add related entity to Tenant
I am starting with abp.io, the free version. I am writing a multitenant app and I need to add a property to the Tenant entity, like "Editions" in the commercial version. So, I read the docs and I know how to add a new value property but not how to manage it. My goal is to have an Edition related to the Tenant and Features related to Edition. My frontend is angular.
I just added a new Guid property to Tenant entity and also I can see it in the Tenants table and the create/edit form, as a textfield with the Guid...
I will appreciate any help or sample. As I am starting my project I can not pay the commercial license rightnow.
Thanks in advance
